# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') when using Vue.use(VueI18n)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm trying to make i18n in my Vue project,
then an error just occur.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
```

here is my project tree:

```
| -- Project
     | -- src
          | -- App.vue
          | -- main.js
          | -- store
               |-- index.js
          | -- lang
               | -- i18n.js
               | -- tw.json
               | -- en.json
```

i18n.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

import tw from './tw.json';
import en from './en.json';

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'tw',
    messages: { tw, en }
});

export default i18n;
```

main.js:

```
...
import i18n from "./lang/i18n";
app.use(i18n);
```

"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-i18n": "^8.26.8",
Node: v14.18.0

Comment: The error in the console is for which file main.js or i18njs

Answer (score 1):

add main js:

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  i18n
}).$mount('#app');
```

and

```
import i18n from "./lang/i18n";
```

change to

```
and * as i18n from "./lang/i18n";
```